# Where Are Attachments Stored?

Tags: apex, visualforce, document

I have uploaded the document in a `Visualforce Page` by using custom controller. But I don't know the exact location of attachment. Its not in My Document.

Comment: Please do not use supplications such as "please" or "urgent" in your questions. You will find the community perfectly willing to help if you ask a well formed question in good faith.

Comment: okay @AdrianLarson

Answer (score 2):

Open Developer console and in the query editor use the following query to find your document/attachment and the folder/parent in which it exists

For documents,

```
Select Id,Name,Folder.Name,createddate from Document order by createddate
```

For Attachments use this query,

```
Select Id,Name,ParentId,Parent.Name,CreatedDate from Attachment order by createddate
```